# CutyCapt with javascript enabled

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to capture html page using cutycapt executable, the issue is when I am setting javascript on and sending some querystring values along with the url

like - http://www.xyz.com/home.html?t=1

I have written a javascript function which gets called on load of the page, and I am using that function to populate a textbox with the querystring value that's passed in the url.

Now the thing is the screen-shot that gets generated is not executing the javascript function at all.

Is there any workaround for this

Comment: I have the same problem, all our contents are done dynamically with javascript and i get a white image as output after waiting 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

As from reading usage documentation I would preffer setting these variables

- `--delay` to 1-5 seconds (depends on how lenghty javascript operations are)
- `--plugins` to `on`
- `--javascript` to `on` (better to explicitly declare it)
- `--js-can-access-clipboard` to `on` (if your script uses clipboard)
- `--java` to `on` (optional)

.

```
% CutyCapt --help
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Usage: CutyCapt --url=http://www.example.org/ --out=localfile.png
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --help                         Print this help page and exit
  --url=<url>                    The URL to capture (http:...|file:...|...)
  --out=<path>                   The target file (.png|pdf|ps|svg|jpeg|...)
  --out-format=<f>               Like extension in --out, overrides heuristic
  --min-width=<int>              Minimal width for the image (default: 800)
  --min-height=<int>             Minimal height for the image (default: 600)
  --max-wait=<ms>                Don't wait more than (default: 90000, inf: 0)
  --delay=<ms>                   After successful load, wait (default: 0)
  --user-styles=<url>            Location of user style sheet, if any
  --header=<name>:<value>        request header; repeatable; some can't be set
  --method=<get|post|put>        Specifies the request method (default: get)
  --body-string=<string>         Unencoded request body (default: none)
  --body-base64=<base64>         Base64-encoded request body (default: none)
  --app-name=<name>              appName used in User-Agent; default is none
  --app-version=<version>        appVers used in User-Agent; default is none
  --user-agent=<string>          Override the User-Agent header Qt would set
  --javascript=<on|off>          JavaScript execution (default: on)
  --java=<on|off>                Java execution (default: unknown)
  --plugins=<on|off>             Plugin execution (default: unknown)
  --private-browsing=<on|off>    Private browsing (default: unknown)
  --auto-load-images=<on|off>    Automatic image loading (default: on)
  --js-can-open-windows=<on|off> Script can open windows? (default: unknown)
  --js-can-access-clipboard=<on|off> Script clipboard privs (default: unknown)
  --print-backgrounds=<on|off>   Backgrounds in PDF/PS output (default: off)
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <f> is svg,ps,pdf,itext,html,rtree,png,jpeg,mng,tiff,gif,bmp,ppm,xbm,xpm
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```